# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- open source wordpress plugins
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3949).

Answer (score 10):

[image: Come build your community]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Software Recommendations]

Comment: A bit too much text?

Comment: @Nemo: That's right, I tried to shorten the text but had no idea how to do... by the way, the "specific needs" part is important, as questions get closed if the requirements are not extremely specific (final goal, features needed, Wordpress version, license, price, at least).

Comment: It seems confusing that this is pointing to a (large) meta thread rather than just stack itself.

Comment: I would have pointed to the site itself, but Gilles (http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/64/gilles) wanted to point to that meta page, and he is an admin so I did not question his advice. Actually I don't mind either way, so I let you decide :-)

Comment: @Rarst [softwarerecs.se] has a perception problem: many users of other Stack Exchange sites believe that if a question is asking for recommendation (“what's the best Wordpress plugin?”), it's fine for SR.SE. We actually have strong quality control, and we have to teach every new user that we aren't Stack Exchange's toilet bowl. I want to shove our quality guidelines in people's faces before they post, because otherwise we shove them after they post and we close their question.

Comment: It's up to you of course, if this makes sense as landing for your stack then it's fine. :)